# Escape mysql table name

Tags: mysql, escaping

How do I escape a table name named `log\'; WAITFOR DELAY \'0:0:5\';--`?

I want to delete the table.

None of these works:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'log\\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\\'0:0:5\\\';--';
SHOW TABLES LIKE "log\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\'0:0:5\\';--";
SHOW TABLES LIKE `log\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\'0:0:5\\';--`;
```

The last one gives an error, while the others gives no results. The error is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`log\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\'0:0:5\\';--`' at line 1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did that table name come from?

Comment: @JamWaffles testing with [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/)

Comment: and extra escapes.  My suggestion would be backtick and tablename. No escapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These statements will return the tablename (if the table exists):

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE "log\\\\'%"

SHOW TABLES LIKE "log\\\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\\\'0:0:5\\\\';--"

SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables 
 WHERE table_name LIKE "log\\\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\\\'0:0:5\\\\';--"
```

To reference the table name in a SQL statement, you'll need to use backticks to enclose the name, for example:

```
SELECT 1 FROM `log\'; WAITFOR DELAY \'0:0:5\';--` LIMIT 1 ;

RENAME TABLE `log\'; WAITFOR DELAY \'0:0:5\';--` TO `foo` ;

DROP TABLE `log\'; WAITFOR DELAY \'0:0:5\';--` ;
```

NOTE: The backslashes and special characters in the name don't need to be escaped when the object name is referenced in a SQL statement, just enclose it in backticks. But those backslashes DO need to be escaped when it's being interpretted as a string literal, as it is in the LIKE predicate.

(I've been there and and done that, creating a wonky table names.)

---

To drop all tables with names starting with `log\'`, I would do it as a two step process. First, I would generate DROP TABLE statements, and then I would execute those statements.

```
SELECT CONCAT('DROP TABLE `',table_name,'`;') 
 FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE "log\\\\'%"
  AND table_schema = DATABASE()
```

Comment: Do you know how to drop all tables starting with log? They all contains special characters.

Comment: Nevermind, I did it with `mysqldump --add-drop-table` and grepping and copying.

Answer (score 0):

```
`log\'; WAITFOR DELAY \'0:0:5\';--`
```

try that.

### EDIT

Edited from

```
`log\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\'0:0:5\\';--`
```

to

```
`log\'; WAITFOR DELAY \'0:0:5\';--`
```

Comment: Results in ```ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`log\\'; WAITFOR DELAY \\'0:0:5\\';--`' at line 1```

Answer (score 0):

Does the table name actually contain \ characters, or is it just `log'; WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:5';--`? Because according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html \ characters are not allowed in table names.

Does this work:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE `log'; WAITFOR DELAY '0:0:5';--`;
```

Comment: Yes it does contain the backslashes